# Finding the number of $n \times n$ elementary matrices over the field $\mathbb{F_p}$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, field-theory, solution-verification

$\mathbf{Attempt:}$

$1.$ We consider the row operation where two rows are swapped. There are $n$ rows of the identity matrix and we "choose" two rows and swap them. Thereby we can obtain $^nC_2$ elementary matrices in this way.

$2.$ Now for the case where we obtain an elementary matrix by multiplying a row of the $n \times n$ identity matrix by some non-zero scalar, we can multiply an arbitrary row by $p-1$ elements. However, multiplying by $1$ would yield the identity matrix. There are $n$ rows, so $n(p-1)$ possibilities, among which $n$ matrices would be the identity matrix. So,  $n(p-2)+1$ distinct elementary matrices arise.

$3.$ Regarding the row operation $R_i+cR_j\mapsto R_i$, where $i\neq j$, firstly we consider $c\neq 0$. We fix an arbitrary row of the identity matrix, say $R_i$ and we are left with $n-1$ other rows which we can multiply with $p-1$ scalars and add to $R_i$. So, $(n-1)(p-1)$ elementary matrices arise when we fix a row. There being $n$ rows, we have $n(n-1)(p-1)$ such possibilites.

$4.$ Finally, we consider the case when $c=0$ and we perform the row operation $R_i+cR_j\mapsto R_i$. In this particular case, $R_i$ remains unchanged, thus we get the identity matrix. We have already taken $I_{n\times n}$ into account (as an elementary matrix).

So in total, there are $^nC_2+n(p-2)+n(n-1)(p-1)+1$ distinct $n\times n$ elementary matrices over $\mathbb{F_p}$.

***Is this correct?***

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is correct. You have done it particularly well. Sorry for it that I have not got enough reputation pts, so I cannot add a comment here.